# Need help about electret microphone

Tags: microphone, arduino-uno, electret, condenser-microphone

I'm using this pre-amplifier circuit for my electret microphone and then feeding the output to A0 analog pin of an Arduino UNO board. For some reason, my serial monitor in the Arduino IDE shows the output at a constant 130, no matter how much sound I make in front of the microphone.

Pre-amplifier circuit is as shown below:

[image: Pre-amplifier circuit]

---

Serial monitor:

[image: Serial monitor]

[This](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Deal-with-Noisy-Neighbors/) is the circuit I'm implementing. My connections for the pre-amplifier part:

- Orange wire for output, connected to A0 pin of Arduino UNO,
- Brown wire is the GND pin from Arduino UNO,
- Red wire is 5 V pin from Arduino UNO,
- electret microphone's green wire is +V<sub>e</sub>,
- White wire is -V<sub>e</sub>.

Thing is, I've implemented the same pre-amplifier circuit as the shown above, but for some reason the sound doesn't get picked up.

My pre-amplifier circuit is as shown below:

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to see if the bias resistor is connected or not and it's impossible to tell if you have not inadvertently connected the microphone up with the wrong polarity.

Comment: by biasing resistors you mean r1, r2, r3? The mic (+)red is green wire and (-)black is white wire.

Comment: Also note that the output of the circuit is AC and will go negative which could damage the microcontroller's ADC.

Comment: I see, but I've seen the same pre amp ckt working for projects without much problems. https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Deal-with-Noisy-Neighbors/   ,                                https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-Project-Baby-Noise-Detection/

Comment: @AyushSinha that might be pure luck. Instructables.com isn't exactly known for being a source of high-quality circuit approaches.

Comment: Measure R2 to check that it is 100 kohm.

Comment: i'll check and let you know. edit: that was the problem, My resistor had a slightly orangish color which I mistook for yellow.

Comment: Really thankful, Just wanna ask one more question. I know that it is common-emitter amplification model which has positive current and voltage gains. Question is, what does the mic output actually give to the arduino (the signal), is it voltage or current?

Comment: A common-emitter amp, because it uses a transistor base as the input, is by definition a current amplifier. If instead you had used a FET preamp, that would be a voltage amplifier (as FET inputs draw essentially no current.)

Comment: I never liked that circuit as an amp for an electret, the input resistance is ill defined, its supposed to be zero since the transistor is working with shunt feedback, but due to the lack of open loop gain the input resistance is far from zero, also, closed loop gain is not well defined and depends on the output resistance of the elements connected to the input. That is without counting the high levels of distortion it will produce. In my opinion this circuit is only useful to trigger a comparator or in non-critical applications. You should really use a good opamp instead.

Answer (score 1):

Measure R2 to check that it is 100 kohm.

> *that was the problem, My resistor had a slightly orangish color which
> I mistook for yellow.*

and from another comment...

> *Really thankful, Just wanna ask one more question. I know that it is
> common-emitter amplification model which has positive current and
> voltage gains. Question is, what does the mic output actually give to
> the arduino (the signal), is it voltage or current?*

The voltage gain is negative because the circuit is inverting the AC input signal.

The amplifier amplifies voltage AND current but, what is given to the arduino, is a voltage signal mainly.

Comment: Why is output voltage signal negative?

Comment: I said the voltage gain is negative. When the input peak is positive the output is at its lowest level and, when the input peak is negative the output is most positive; it inverts the signal.

Comment: @AyushSinha It can be negative on the ADC's input because of the C2 capacitor. Essentially it is forming a differentiating RC network with the input resistance of the ADC, which is usually tied to somewhere near the ground. Therefore, half of the signal will be negative. You can place a 100k/100k resistor divider from arduino power to ground to get 2.5V and connect C2 capacitor there, and only then to the arduino ADC. Also, don't expect superb audio quality due to the 10-bit low-sample-rate (due to the UART overhead).